# AWS Java SDK Error - withPermissionsBoundary for IAM user

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Using AWS SDK for JAVA, i want to limit access to a single Bucket folder.
When i try to run this code to assign permissions to a new IAM user:

```
final AmazonIdentityManagement client = AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
            .build();

    try {                       
        String permissionsBoundary = 
        "{" + 
        "\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"," + 
        "  \"Statement\": [" +
        "    {" + 
        "      \"Effect\": \"Allow\"," + 
        "      \"Action\": "+
        "       [" + 
        "        \"s3:PutObject\"," + 
        "        \"s3:GetObject\"," + 
        "        \"s3:DeleteObject\"" + 
        "      ]," + 
        "      \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*\"" + 
        "    }" + 
        "  ]" + 
        "}";

        CreateUserRequest request = new CreateUserRequest()
                .withUserName(usernameIAM)
                .withPermissionsBoundary(permissionsBoundary);
        CreateUserResult response = client.createUser(request);
```

i get this error:

```
ARN {&quot;Version&quot;:&quot;2012-10-17&quot;,&quot;Statement&quot;:[{&quot;Effect&quot;:&quot;Allow&quot;,&quot;Action&quot;:&quot;s3:ListAllMyBuckets&quot;,&quot;Resource&quot;:&quot;arn:aws:s3:::*&quot;}]} is not valid. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: ...xxxxxxxxxxxx...)[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@2f3a60a1
```

i followed this 
[Amazon IAM Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

what is the correct use of the method `withPermissionsBoundary` and how is the rule correctly defined?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the following:

```
ARN 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
is not valid.
```

This is clearly not a valid ARN, because it isn't an ARN at all, it is a policy. Where is this used in your code? Wherever it is used, you need to replace it with the correct ARN.

Comment: Thanks, the error message is clear, but can you show me an example of correct ARN?

Comment: My point is that the error is not from the code that you posted. Also, a valid ARN depends on the situation, for an S3 bucket, arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME is a valid ARN.